# HTTP vs HTTPS from developer view

Tags: http, https

I need to build a Web site which would have a secure connection (HTTPS) on some pages. I need to know if there will be a difference for me (as a developer) while I will write the code? I must treat differently some data or what? What is the main difference from back-end view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the backend point of view, there is no difference.  The difference between the two is the TCP connection between the server and the client.  Https will be encrypted, http is not of course, but it's all decrypted by the time it hits your code.  The server will have some flags available so you can determine whether the connection is http or https (names vary depending on the server) but unless you're using that information to change the behavior of the page, you don't need to worry about it.